# Laravel limit in whereIn clause

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I'm using laravel 5.7

I have query with whereIn clause

In my controller I have query like this:

```php
$post = Post::whereIn('reply_from_id', [1,2])
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

I get output like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "test reply id 2",
        "reply_from_id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "test reply id 1",
        "reply_from_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "title": "test reply id 1 again",
        "reply_from_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "title": "test reply id 1 again and again",
        "reply_from_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "title": "test reply id 2 again",
        "reply_from_id": 2
    }
]
```

I want to limit output only show 2 data every ID

for example:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "test reply id 2",
        "reply_from_id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "test reply id 1",
        "reply_from_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "title": "test reply id 1 again",
        "reply_from_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "title": "test reply id 2 again",
        "reply_from_id": 2
    },

]
```

I try using `take()` like this:

```php
$post = Post::whereIn('reply_from_id', [1,2])
            ->take(2)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

But this is only show data like this

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "test reply id 2",
        "reply_from_id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "test reply id 1",
        "reply_from_id": 1
    }
]
```

How to limit data in whereIn clause ?

Answer (score 1):

You can group by reply_from_id to get 1 record for every id

Use the [use](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) keyword to bind variables into the function's scope.

Closures may inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be declared in the function header [using use].

```
$everyHow = 3;
$ids      = [1,2];
$post     = Post::whereIn("posts.id", function ($query) use ($everyHow, $ids) {
    $query->select("p.id")->from('posts p')
    ->whereRaw('p.id = posts.id')
    ->whereIn("p.reply_from_id", $ids)
    ->orderBy("p.id", "desc")->limit($everyHow);
})->get();
```

**EDIT**

Explanation: Fetching properly data under the consideration of `id` which is a primary key and 3 records every reply_from_id must have a unique id to identify and fetch in query hence, I took wherein `id`, is that clear?

Comment: Sorry, get 1 record just for example. In real case I want to get 3 record every ID. I will edit my question

Comment: Now check my answer

Comment: i got error `ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "posts"`

Comment: Check now I made some changes

Comment: Why using whereIn id ?
Where i can check if reply_from_id in 1 and 2 ?

Comment: Nothing has changed in the output

Answer (score 0):

```php
$post = Post::whereIn('reply_from_id', [1,2])
            ->limit(1)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

```php
$post = Post::whereIn('reply_from_id', [1,2])
            ->limit(1)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
```